# C# ML predict weird value

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I recently got interested in machine learning in C#. I download sample code from Microsoft Website and I wanted to test it.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

class Program
{
    public class HouseData
    {
        public float Size { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prediction
    {
        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        // 1. Import or create training data
        HouseData[] houseData = {
               new HouseData() { Size = 100, Price = 10 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 200, Price = 20 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 300, Price = 30 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 400, Price = 40 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 500, Price = 50 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 600, Price = 60 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 700, Price = 70 },
               new HouseData() { Size = 800, Price = 80 } };
        IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(houseData);

        // 2. Specify data preparation and model training pipeline
        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new[] { "Size" })
            .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "Price", 
       maximumNumberOfIterations: 100));

        // 3. Train model
        var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

        // 4. Make a prediction
        var size = new HouseData() { Size = 400 };
        var price = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<HouseData, Prediction>(model).Predict(size);

        Console.WriteLine($"Predicted price for size: {size.Size} is {price.Price}");
    }
}
```

I modify training data (add some more records) and try check price value when size is 400. Program return weird values, example:

```
First run: -5,815702
Second run: 30,172789
Third run: 24,27233
```

In my opinion, it is logical that the program should return the number 40. How do I make the mistake that the results are completely different?

Comment: Try setting the `seed` if you need deterministic outputs: `new MLContext(seed: 0)`

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In relation to the different results:**

See the documentation added [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/commit/9b51bca9a78a3e304eb28409210841fec1b683c3) regarding the `seed`.

And also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.sdcaregressiontrainer?view=ml-dotnet#training-algorithm-details) regarding the specific SDCA options:

> For reproducible results, it is recommended that one sets 'Shuffle' to False and 'NumThreads' to 1

Many operations in ML.Net are non-deterministic.  You're seeing this because you're training the model on each program run and the training itself is non-deterministic due to the factors highlighted above.

Therefore if you *need* to re-train a model with a deterministic output, you can set the `seed` parameter in the `MLContext` constructor, `Shuffle` to `false` and `NumThreads` to `1`.

Typically for supervised learning techniques like regression, the training would be performed separately to the prediction, storing the trained model in state to be subsequently used for multiple predictions.

**In relation to your expected value of 40:**

It looks like you're expecting the result of a linear regression.  The `SdcaRegressionTrainer` is not the same as linear regression - this is reflected in the result that you're seeing.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.sdcaregressiontrainer?view=ml-dotnet) for more detailed information on the `SdcaRegressionTrainer`.

Comment: I try use `seed` and run program several times and it return values aprox 31. 
Close, but that's not it yet

Comment: @Adam I assumed 'weird' was referring to the different results. I've updated the answer in regards to expected results.